# Jquery Sortable Box Restrictions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

For those familiar with sortable created by Jonny von Adrian (http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/),

Is there any way to say, restrict the elements of a box such that they can only be dragged in between itself and another box, even if there are multiple boxes? Right now I'm creating an interface that allows users to drag from a topic box into another topic box, but this is causing a problem since they can drag an element from the "times" box into the "courses" box and vice versa.

Also I was wondering if there was a way to expand the boxes to a certain height when there's nothing in them. Right now it's somewhat confusing if a box is empty since the user may not know that items can be dragged into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first time I have seen it, but I might be able to help a little bit after I had a quick skim over his [documentation](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#docs). It looks like there are two included options relevant to your interests, ["exclude"](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#container-options) and "isValidTarget".

"isValidTarget" expects a callback function, which gets called with an $item parameter, which contains – you guessed it – the element being dragged, and a second parameter, "container", which is the element receiving the the item being dragged.  The rest is up to you. Have fun!

Here is a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZP93H/) of a very basic use of exclude:

```
$(function() {
  $("ol.example").sortable({
    containerPath: "> li",
    containerSelector: "ol",
    exclude: "ol ol > li"
  });
  $("ol.example ol").sortable();
});

<ol class='example'>
  <li>
    Restricted
    <ol>
      <li>Items</li>
      <li>cannot</li>
      <li>be added</li>
      <li>Here.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Open 1
    <ol>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Open 2</li>
  <li>Open 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked the documentation :/